# Faster way to load JS Array using jquery - Request/Handling Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following to array variables:

```
var states_list = {
    '1': ['747','748','749','750','751','752','753','754','755','756','757','758','759','760','761','762','763','764','765','766','767','768','769'],
    '2': ['500','501','502','503','504','505','506','507','508'],
    '3': ['516','517','518','519','520','521','522'],
    '4': ['523','524','525','526','527','528','529','530','531'],
    '5': ['544','545','546','547','548','549'],
    '6': ['537','538','539','540','541','542','543'],
    '7': ['550','551','552','553','554','555','556','557','558','559'],
    '8': ['560','561','562','563','564','565','566','567','568','569','570','571','572','573','574','575','576','577','578','579','580','581','582','583','584','585'],
    '9': ['586','587','588','589','590','591','592','593','594','595','596','597','598','599','600','601','602','603','604','605','606','607','608','609','610','611','612','613','614','615','616','617','618','619','620','621'],
    '10': ['622','623','624','625','626','627','628','629','630','631','632','633','634','635','636','637','638','639','640','641','642','643','644','645','646','647','648','649','650','651','652','653','654','655','656','657','658'],
    '11': ['659','660','661','662','663','664','665','666','667','668','669','670','671','672'],
    '12': ['673','674','675','676','677','678','679','680','681','682','683','684','685','686','687','688','689'],
    '13': ['690','691','692','693','694','695','696','697','698','699'],
    '14': ['700','701','702','703','704','705','706','707','708','709','710','711','712','713'],
    '15': [],
    '16': ['509','510','511','512','513','514','515'],
    '17': ['714','715','716','717','718','719'],
    '18': ['720','721','722','723','724','725','726','727','728','729','730'],
    '19': ['731','732','733','734','735','736','737','738'],
    '20': ['739','740','741','742','743','744','745','746'],
    '21': ['770','771','772','773','774','775','776','777','778'],
    '22': ['779','780','781','782','783','784','785','786','787','788','789','790','791','792','793','794','795','796','797','798'],
    '23': ['799','800','801','802','803','804','805','806','807','808','809','810','811','812','813','814','815','816','817','818','819','820','821','822','823'],
    '24': ['824','825','826','827','828','829','830','831'],
    '25': ['832','833','834','835','836','837','838','839','840','841','842','843'],
    '26': ['844','845','846','847','848'],
    '27': ['849','850','851','852','853','854','855','856','857','858','859','860','861','862','863','864','865','866','867','868','869','870','871'],
    '28': ['872','873','874','875','876','877','878','879','880','881'],
    '29': ['882','883','884','885','886','887','888','889','890','891'],
    '30': ['892','893','894','895','896','897','898','899','900','901','902'],
    '31': ['903','904','905','906','907','908','909','910','911','912','913','914','915','916','917','918','919','920','921'],
    '32': ['922','923','924','925','926','927','928','929','930','931','932','933','934','935','936'],
    '33': ['937','938','939','940','941','942','943','944','945','946','947','948','949','950','951','952','953','954','955','956','957','958','959','960','961','962','963','964','965'],
    '34': ['532','533','534','535','536']
}
```

And this one (omitted due to its size):

```
var districts_list = {
        '500': ['1006', '2671', '3312', '3444', '3873', '4165', '4191', '4649', '5156'],
        '501': ['1322', '3121', '5810', '6141'],
        '502': ['1335', '1793', '1850', '2372', '3275', '5186', '5348', '5496', '5667', '6091'],
        '503': ['1642', '2379', '4563', '5675', '5909', '6075', '6344'],
        '504': ['3858', '3868', '4107', '4590'],
        '505': ['1002', '1108', '1517', '2853', '3271', '3719', '5000', '5251', '5410'],
        '506': ['1339', '2151', '3150', '4196', '5287'],
        '507': ['1500', '2970', '3074', '3763', '4619', '4856', '5256', '5257', '5258', '5821'],
        '508': ['2173', '2174', '2175', '2176'],
        '509': ['1232', '1537', '3867', '3895', '4601', '4791', '5008', '5761'],
        '510': ['2638', '3003', '3883', '5471', '6150'],
        '511': ['1045', '3486', '4566', '5470', '6242'],
        '512': ['3151', '4425', '5465', '5781'],
        '513': ['1777', '2374', '4420', '4421', '4940'],
        '514': ['1214', '3862', '5253', '5429', '5987'],
        '515': ['2171', '2325', '3005', '3716'],
        '516': ['1352', '1509', '1683', '1912', '1921', '1968', '2001', '2017', '2038', '2050', '2114', '2468', '3488', '3637', '3673', '4053', '4415', '4939', '5070', '5557', '6431', '6458'],
        '517': ['1137', '1334', '1671', '1854', '1881', '1914', '1933', '1959', '1991', '1996', '2033', '2035', '2058', '2082', '2672', '2720', '2884', '3339', '3694', '3869', '4058', '4288', '4400', '4439', '4546', '4668', '5072', '5664', '5745'],
        '518': ['1143', '1407', '1626', '1669', '1877', '1982', '1995', '2043', '2048', '2075', '2628', '3110', '3176', '3220', '3225', '3691', '4224', '4270', '4361', '4653', '4740', '4844', '5933', '6228', '6334', '6445'],
        '519': ['1920', '2016', '2094', '2096', '2371', '2681', '3887', '4870'],
        '520': ['2062', '2113', '2909', '5341', '5849', '6418'],
        '521': ['1249', '2002', '2066', '2083', '2088', '2112', '2572', '2633', '3038', '3178', '3236', '3240', '3445', '3811', '4286', '4327', '4376', '4446', '4508', '4730', '4911', '5328', '5349', '5637', '6132', '6197'],
        '522': ['1484', '1548', '1936', '2014', '2063', '2621', '2885', '2893', '3402', '4112', '4637', '4671', '5944'],
        '523': ['2990', '3190', '3731', '4675', '4679', '5219'],
        '524': ['1043', '1049', '1151', '1458', '2264', '2384', '2842', '3079', '3098', '3362', '4096', '4249', '4283', '4610', '4731', '4898', '5820', '5855'],
        '525': ['2928', '2929', '2930', '2931', '3118', '3643', '4100', '5978'],
        '526': ['1576', '3061', '6061', '6348'],
        '527': ['3436', '3437', '3438', '3439', '3440', '5013'],
        '528': ['3584', '4046', '4047', '4048', '4733', '6173'],
        '529': ['1577', '2116', '3192', '4267', '5274', '5483'],
        '530': ['1050', '2526', '3585', '5269', '5270', '5271', '5272', '5273', '5300', '5301', '5655', '5838', '5871', '5872', '6371'],
        '531': ['1557', '2288', '2803', '4000', '4976', '4977', '5255', '5783', '6128'],
        '532': ['1272', '1331', '1368', '2191', '2530', '2664', '2910', '3237', '4308', '4397', '4692', '4702', '4850', '5137', '5214', '5368', '5604'],
        '533': ['2346', '2387', '2869', '4140', '4150', '4346', '4414', '4554', '4698', '4737', '4892', '5028', '5160', '5280', '5302', '6013', '6169', '6558'],
        '534': ['2303', '2386', '2753', '3161', '3479', '4092', '4443', '4624', '5120', '5325', '6146', '6472'],
        '535': ['1572', '1874', '2181', '2309', '2396', '2743', '3936', '3946', '3993', '4122', '4144', '4316', '4764', '5369', '5552', '6149', '6340'],
        '536': ['2136', '2349', '2409', '2410', '2663', '3205', '3229', '3736', '3900', '4127', '4324', '6081', '6380', '6526', '6593'],
        '537': ['2560'],
        '538': ['1892', '2419', '2561', '2757', '2953', '3031', '4348', '5883', '5902'],
        '539': ['1890', '2304', '2562', '2679', '3027', '3882', '5180', '5315', '5912'],
        '540': ['2010', '2553', '2563', '2950', '2951', '3687', '4391', '4510', '4641', '5361', '6062'],
        '541': ['1856', '2056', '2068', '2240', '2564', '2608', '3223', '3650', '3807', '4511', '4843'],
        '542': ['2023', '2565', '3004', '3159', '4272', '4626', '5992'],
        '543': ['3070', '3071', '4823'],
        '544': ['1738', '2231', '3690', '4300', '6206'],
        '545': ['1131', '1179', '1485', '1699', '1712', '3513', '3514', '3976', '4847', '5709', '6094', '6190', '6249', '6250'],
        '546': ['1132', '1180', '3333', '5710', '6251'],
        '547': ['3476', '3776', '4299', '4549', '4749', '4935', '5873'],
        '548': ['1704', '2710', '5814', '6017'],
        '549': ['2238', '2411', '3183', '3194', '3195', '3196'],
        '550': ['1231', '1459', '3780', '3781', '3902', '4007', '4035', '4611'],
        '551': ['1456', '2690', '3515', '4008', '4044', '4597', '4598', '4953', '5928', '5932'],
        '552': ['1046', '1047', '1444', '2130', '2438', '2451', '2480', '2945', '3012', '5542', '5770'],
        '553': ['1319', '2586', '4029', '4365', '5765', '5824', '5825'],
        '554': ['2574', '3284', '3285', '3779', '3906', '5239', '5317', '5750'],
        '555': ['1432', '3700', '4020', '4556', '4595', '5169'],
        '556': ['1582', '3259', '3901', '4620', '6332', '6333'],
        '557': ['2172', '3865', '4027', '4173', '4956', '5062'],
        '558': ['4033', '5011', '5012', '5014', '5712', '6069', '6070', '6071', '6159', '6396'],
        '559': ['2134', '2573', '2575', '2576', '2645', '3185', '4507', '4596', '6096'],
        '560': ['1157', '1250', '1337', '1676', '1875', '1943', '1981', '2018', '2020', '2039', '2040', '2052', '2099', '2155', '2513', '2915', '3086', '3639', '3764', '3767', '4076', '4227', '4366', '4407', '4516', '4530', '4930', '4931', '5569'],
        '561': ['1487', '1964', '1979', '2021', '2037', '2054', '2059', '2064', '2081', '2467', '3467', '4128', '4234', '4499', '5026', '5487'],
        '562': ['1267', '1354', '1385', '1515', '1816', '1880', '1916', '1918', '1935', '1958', '1967', '1975', '1993', '2011', '2086', '2090', '2091', '2331', '2332', '2721', '2874', '2888', '3080', '3454', '3489', '3660', '3856', '4317', '4367', '4378', '4411', '4531', '4660'],
        '563': ['1197', '1673', '1831', '1860', '1919', '2137', '2604', '3109', '3728', '4514', '4700', '4735', '4871'],
        '564': ['1616', '1644', '1907', '1937', '1969', '1990', '2060', '2065', '2078', '2105', '2569', '2762', '3446', '4225', '4276', '4360', '4552', '4868', '4893', '5063', '5615', '6002'],
        '565': ['1756', '1940', '2030', '2032', '2079', '2087', '2106', '2139', '2319', '2601', '2606', '2610', '4377', '4517', '4933', '5547', '5669', '5736', '5737', '5738', '5801', '6008', '6009', '6011', '6261', '6352', '6399'],
        '566': ['1363', '1677', '1678', '1909', '1915', '1955', '1977', '1989', '2044', '2055', '2084', '2110', '2460', '2570', '2623', '2717', '2864', '2872', '3493', '3726', '3733', '4233', '4292', '4389', '4503', '4895', '4910', '5087', '5093', '5167', '5495', '5559', '5640'],
        '567': ['1353', '1401', '1903', '1953', '1963', '1965', '1972', '1973', '2000', '2036', '2041', '2049', '2077', '2605', '2771', '2932', '3365', '3388', '3606', '3725', '4232', '4362', '4385', '4408', '4441', '4462', '4492', '4867', '4908', '4932', '5060', '5407', '5486'],
        '568': ['1123', '1150', '1175', '1198', '1303', '1305', '1306', '1307', '1492', '1680', '1681', '1923', '1924', '1931', '1942', '1945', '1947', '2102', '3108', '3482', '3765', '4934', '4989', '5642', '5668', '5746', '6358'],
        '569': ['1333', '3384', '4542', '4869'],
        '570': ['2026', '2027', '2028', '2029'],
        '571': ['1925', '1966', '2057', '2532', '2933', '3720', '5885', '6050', '6053'],
        '572': ['1202', '1682', '1853', '1917', '1934', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '2855', '2987', '4011', '4568', '5342', '5362', '5646', '5671', '5674', '5899', '5904', '5905', '6044'],
        '573': ['1359', '1524', '1525', '1526', '1527', '1528', '2597', '2617', '3840', '4066', '4732', '4734', '4981'],
        '574': ['1196', '1679', '1879', '1882', '1904', '1908', '1929', '1941', '1960', '1961', '1971', '2019', '2047', '2080', '2085', '2095', '2217', '2449', '2454', '2592', '2684', '3025', '3136', '3490', '3492', '3849', '4093', '4368', '4500', '4502', '4929', '5045', '5644', '5650'],
        '575': ['1660', '1661', '1662', '1663', '1664', '1665', '5929'],
        '576': ['1158', '1176', '1195', '1518', '2015', '2072', '2073', '2097', '2180', '2230', '2341', '2355', '2364', '2779', '2826', '2883', '2890', '2966', '3135', '3456', '3569', '4055', '4219', '4223', '4344', '4413', '4435', '4504', '4701', '4706', '5215', '5716', '5806', '5809'],
        '577': ['1138', '1146', '1264', '1323', '1709', '1876', '1992', '2286', '2322', '2492', '2536', '2599', '2698', '2813', '2843', '2971', '3087', '3227', '3241', '3453', '3543', '3567', '5482', '5553', '5638', '5701', '6303', '6517'],
        '578': ['1910', '1926', '1928', '1949', '1956', '1962', '2012', '2022', '2025', '2046', '2061', '2098', '2138', '2327', '2483', '2568', '2589', '2719', '2766', '2865', '3224', '3290', '3434', '3610', '3663', '3704', '4194', '4388', '4513', '5247', '5484', '5614'],
        '579': ['1152', '1338', '1366', '1957', '1998', '2045', '2154', '2620', '2622', '2716', '3082', '3458', '3491', '3502', '3638', '3641', '4338', '4469', '4909', '5488', '5639', '5721', '5850'],
        '580': ['2070', '2071', '2487', '2998', '3094', '3459', '4581'],
        '581': ['1523', '1939', '2031', '2179', '3516', '4392', '5189', '5679'],
        '582': ['1386', '1488', '1905', '1938', '1980', '2008', '2009', '2013', '2618', '2631', '2894', '2895', '2896', '3137', '3200', '3325', '3457', '3640', '4321', '4422', '4573', '4874', '4982', '5001', '5852', '6086', '6130', '6131', '6153', '6226', '6227'],
        '583': ['1035', '1684', '1859', '1861', '1906', '1922', '1930', '1951', '1970', '1974', '1978', '2007', '2051', '2069', '2108', '2356', '2722', '2887', '3455', '3699', '4098', '4229', '4290', '5485', '5648', '5653', '5666', '5848', '5947', '6459'],
        '584': ['1362', '1675', '1878', '1911', '1932', '1944', '1946', '1948', '1950', '1952', '1954', '1976', '1994', '1997', '2067', '2074', '2076', '2089', '2115', '2354', '2437', '2579', '2580', '2704', '2718', '2742', '2755', '2957', '3483', '4075', '4198', '4222', '4475'],
        '585': ['1406', '1927', '1999', '2093', '2450', '3475', '6455'],
        '586': ['1019', '1365', '1606', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2034', '2053', '2156', '2313', '2662', '2802', '2877', '2936', '2985', '3097', '3242', '3644', '3741', '4197', '4551', '5124', '5408', '6427'],
        '587': ['1018', '1069', '1095', '1188', '1714', '1763', '1801', '2399', '2849', '2859', '2882', '2959', '3144', '3329', '3330', '3941', '4274', '4579', '4648', '4728', '4773', '4863', '5035', '5061', '5306', '5609'],
        '588': ['1302', '1733', '1868', '2229', '2413', '2737', '2749', '3903', '4057', '4061', '4116', '4151', '4318', '5080', '5082', '5190', '5210', '5608', '6082', '6154', '6522'],
        '589': ['1222', '1387', '1510', '1553', '1752', '1851', '2340', '2412', '2759', '3037', '3327', '3539', '4153', '4691', '4876'],
        '590': ['1356', '1521', '1796', '1871', '2359', '2695', '2784', '2812', '2974', '3142', '3226', '4119', '4474', '4782', '5265', '6133', '6137', '6236', '6300', '6545'],
        '591': ['2330', '2752', '2763', '2780', '2997', '3066', '3088', '3450', '3962', '5161', '5263', '5686', '6398', '6479', '6564'],
        '592': ['3628', '3629', '3630', '3631'],
        '593': ['1112', '1125', '1379', '1741', '1897', '2700', '2860', '3046', '3143', '3961', '4067', '4143', '4177', '5111', '5193', '5261', '5452', '6172', '6562'],
        '594': ['2103', '2408', '2593', '2612', '2624', '2653', '2693', '2694', '2847', '2873', '2946', '3078', '3806', '3956', '4134', '6049', '6055'],
        '595': ['1514', '1884', '1895', '2161', '2324', '2609', '2675', '2701', '2764', '2846', '2858', '2871', '2956', '3024', '3138', '3139', '3140', '3141', '3730', '4139', '4572', '4713', '4765', '6306', '6324', '6500'],
        '596': ['2362', '2375', '2401', '2652', '2761', '2868', '2965', '3794', '3940', '3969', '4158', '4707', '5115', '5119', '5414', '5601', '5681', '5729', '5943', '6014'],
        '597': ['1235', '1551', '1795', '2333', '2421', '2903', '3958', '4167', '4722', '5685', '6056', '6509'],
        '598': ['1499', '1501', '1798', '2271', '2385', '2388', '2389', '2611', '2616', '2619', '2889', '3128', '3740', '4121', '4163', '4477', '4760', '4795', '4873', '5262', '5415', '5554', '6230', '6548', '6582'],
        '599': ['1351', '2637', '3431', '4509', '5347', '5566'],
        '600': ['1343', '1350', '1494', '1506', '2754', '2866', '3624', '3703', '4291', '4580', '4852', '4872', '4889', '4912', '5424', '5808', '6426', '6434'],
        '601': ['1057', '1382', '1495', '2024', '2432', '2603', '2750', '2867', '2948', '2978', '3033', '3041', '3604', '4328', '4548', '4881', '4882', '4883', '4884', '4885', '4886', '4980', '5563', '5573', '5713', '5744', '5887', '6440'],
        '602': ['1284', '1384', '1425', '1505', '1641', '2417', '2815', '3517', '4569', '4987', '5612', '6181', '6323', '6457', '6566'],
        '603': ['1341', '1652', '1666', '1898', '2588', '2595', '2658', '2669', '2986', '3218', '3289', '4138', '4937', '5118', '6243', '6335'],
        '604': ['1252', '1504', '1670', '1765', '2135', '2403', '2777', '2822', '2825', '2911', '2967', '2977', '3067', '3676', '3770', '4125', '4137', '4156', '4269', '4890', '5234', '5623', '5699', '5725', '5890', '6134'],
        '605': ['1342', '1364', '1748', '1791', '1808', '2600', '3081', '3099', '3403', '3568', '4301', '5089', '5533', '5576', '5957', '6284', '6432'],
        '606': ['1701', '2165', '2166', '2292', '2435', '2850', '2854', '2886', '2955', '3924', '3995', '5198', '6501', '6555'],
        '607': ['1747', '2285', '2378', '2397', '2418', '2426', '2878', '2982', '3132', '3217', '4136', '4616', '4845', '4878', '5951', '6054', '6089', '6290', '6527'],
        '608': ['1327', '1454', '2657', '2767', '2901', '2976', '3014', '3028', '3820', '3947', '4078', '4570', '5837', '6502'],
        '609': ['1668', '1746', '1896', '2365', '2781', '2819', '3049', '3510', '4126', '4294', '4543', '4544', '4576', '4696', '5017', '5036', '5514', '5696', '6503'],
        '610': ['1218', '2153', '2343', '2594', '2641', '2782', '3277', '3853', '6384'],
        '611': ['1451', '2101', '2225', '2284', '2360', '2470', '2566', '2567', '2699', '2942', '3771', '3772', '4545', '4787', '5688', '5891', '6059', '6102', '6297', '6499', '6523'],
        '612': ['1674', '1757', '2216', '2736', '2809', '2852', '2857', '2989', '3095', '3432', '4440', '4655', '5548', '5603', '5875', '6229', '6525', '6549', '6553'],
        '613': ['1114', '1361', '1535', '1658', '2104', '3952', '4600', '4650', '4846', '4938', '5881', '6376', '6460', '6477'],
        '614': ['1657', '1685', '1771', '2760', '2765', '2851', '2862', '2870', '2879', '3000', '3026', '3084', '3324', '3996', '4235', '4621', '4859', '4993'],
        '615': ['1797', '2434', '2769', '3219', '3414', '4372', '4394', '4995', '5088', '5163', '5212', '5555', '5705', '5717'],
        '616': ['1099', '1276', '1378', '1507', '1574', '1750', '2376', '2578', '2783', '4220', '4776', '5742', '5803', '5807', '6161', '6336', '6385', '6386', '6387'],
        '617': ['1020', '1248', '1672', '1809', '2226', '2227', '2607', '2979', '3222', '3433', '3768', '4293', '4418', '5551', '5798', '5854', '6043', '6461'],
        '618': ['4583', '4584', '4585', '4586', '4587'],
        '619': ['1153', '5085', '5416', '5418', '6216'],
        '620': ['1381', '1872', '2293', '2337', '2370', '2469', '3923', '4124', '4574', '5281', '5282', '5283', '5284', '5285', '5286', '6136'],
        '621': ['3766', '6072', '6073', '6076', '6077'],
        '622': ['1324', '1388', '2100', '2305', '2369', '2383', '2392', '2393', '2708', '2751', '2772', '3501', '4054', '4640', '4880', '5024', '5307', '5439', '5513', '5577', '5607', '6079', '6083', '6541'],
        '623': ['1604', '1703', '1902', '2111', '2423', '3130', '3626', '4315', '4763', '4797', '5305', '5698', '5734', '5884', '6021', '6078', '6162', '6237', '6560', '6573'],
        '624': ['1059', '1102', '1154', '1268', '1326', '2433', '2644', '2648', '2655', '2682', '2775', '2778', '3047', '3443', '3818', '4052', '4330', '4461', '4553', '4793', '4920', '5293', '5440', '5692', '5700', '5724', '5728', '5732', '5948', '6155', '6381', '6579'],
        '625': ['1372', '2308', '2420', '2471', '2810', '2814', '2943', '3072', '3228', '3292', '3953', '4118', '4129', '4298', '4472', '4482', '4699', '4704', '4849', '4875', '5018', '5294', '6042'],
        '626': ['2968', '3959', '4642'],
        '627': ['1253', '1883', '2118', '2206', '2352', '2358', '2674', '2897', '2958', '3623', '3852', '4670', '5162', '5183', '6543', '6581'],
        '628': ['1399', '1550', '2880', '2891', '2905', '2935', '3472', '3633', '3742', '4135', '4162', '4404', '4476', '4697', '4727', '5691', '5845'],
        '629': ['1749', '2367', '2676', '2848', '2863', '2980', '3050', '3055', '3332', '3735', '4141', '4157', '4271', '4434', '4498', '4687', '5490', '6518'],
        '630': ['1159', '1286', '2213', '2954', '4104', '4120', '4231', '4780', '4855', '5620', '6080', '6319'],
        '631': ['1193', '1216', '1263', '1818', '2577', '2651', '2665', '2926', '3945', '4142', '4159', '4738', '4790', '4848', '5116', '5129', '5195', '5442', '5550'],
        '632': ['2904', '3622', '3724', '5880'],
        '633': ['1325', '2152', '2190', '2347', '2402', '2613', '2666', '3039', '3328', '3955', '3957', '3960', '4155', '4228', '4853', '4862', '5579', '6298', '6304'],
        '634': ['1265', '1768', '1865', '2345', '2550', '3235', '3238', '4751', '4767', '5213', '5413', '5682', '5882', '5949', '6039', '6322', '6453', '6544'],
        '635': ['3632', '4473'],
...
}
```

I want to populate those data into my select box quickly. So far i have this code:

```
if(typeof selectedProvince != 'undefined' && typeof selectedState != 'undefined') {

    // Iterate through var districts_list to look for province ID based on var selectedState value
    $.each(districts_list, function(key, value) {
        if( ($.inArray(''+selectedState, value)) >= 0 ) {
            // Assign var selectedProvince with province ID
            selectedDistrict = key;
        }
    });

    // Iterate through var states_list to look for province ID based on var selectedState value
    $.each(states_list, function(key, value) {
        if( ($.inArray(''+selectedDistrict, value)) >= 0 ) {
            // Assign var selectedProvince with province ID
            selectedProvince = key;
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        // Pre-select province
        $('#id_province option[value=' + selectedProvince + ']').attr('selected', true);

        // Initiate filterOn plugin (the cities based on province filter)
        $('#id_district').filterOn('#id_province', states_list);

        // Pre-select district
        $('#id_district option[value=' + selectedDistrict + ']').attr('selected', true);
        $('#id_state').filterOn('#id_district', districts_list);

        // Pre-select state
        $('.id_state option[value=' + selectedState + ']').attr('selected', true);
    });
}
```

The code can execute correctly and both select boxes can be populated, the problem is that it is taking too long.

I am wondering if i can speed this up or perhaps put a spinner or loading bar until it populate correctly.

I am constrained with how the JSON data is structured, meaning that i cannot change anything to it.

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks

**Edit #1**
The javascript and the html is on a separate file

Here's the HTML that contains that select box

```
<select name="" id="id_district" style="width:104%; height:37px;" ></select>
<select name="id_state" id="id_state" style="width:104%; height:37px;" >
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: Am I blind or just miss a thing? I don't see the part where you create the select boxes. Without your full code it is hard to say, where you could be faster. You should edit your question and add the full request/handling code.

Comment: what purpose has this concatenation `''+selectedState`?

Comment: @eisbehr i modified the question

Comment: @madalinivascu i have a typo, it suppose to be an empty space '_'

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan why do you need a empty space in that space?

Comment: I still don't see the ajax request and the createion of your select options.

Comment: **''+** is used to convert the integer to a string - all the values in the array are strings, so he needs to pass a string to $.inArray ;)

Comment: js usually takes care of of that @metal03326

Comment: @eisbehr please ignore the ajax part, this mostly done in browser/local using javascript only.

Comment: @madalinivascu No it doesn't - try in your console **$.inArray(1,['1'])** vs **$.inArray('1',['1'])** and you'll see ;)

Comment: @metal03326 i see this is a more strict comparison (===) involving the types as well

Answer (score 0):

You have too much data and searching for the correct state or district using `.inArray` and `.each` takes linear time as those iterate through every item and do the comparison to find the array containing the district/state.

I would suggest pre-calculate the province a district belongs to and store them in a big array, maybe save this lookup table in a JSON file on your server. Then load this lookup table using ajax.

For example let's say I have pre-calculated a big array called DistrictProvinceMapping. I need to find the province the district belongs to.I just get the code through DistrictProvinceMapping[690], which returns 13.

I can then pre-select my province select box.

This will reduce your time complexity of your search to O(1)

Alternatively, if not constrained and if the data is stored in the DB, create a SQL View that acts as a lookup table and use Ajax to let the server do the lookup so the big array doesn't have to be loaded on client machine.